# Is this exchange for developer questions only?

Tags: discussion

Awesome glad to see this community go live.

Are user level questions welcomed here or is it focused on questions for developers building on top of EOS?

Answer (score 5):

This site should be a place to get answers to most of your questions about EOS, both technical and non-technical.  If we limit the site to only technical questions, then people who are interested in what makes EOS better/different from other technologies will have to find some other place to ask those questions.  And those sites won't have the same permanence as the StackExchange site.

Answer (score 4):

Since the tagging on StackExchange is quite sophisticated I expect we should be able to handle code specific questions and less technical ones here. API tags such as `multi_index` should help separate when searching from someone looking for `arbitrator` imho.

Answer (score 1):

Appropriately tagged user level questions are fine. The Ethereum site functions much in the same way where a bulk of the questions are development-related but there are still quite a few user-related questions that aren't explicitly related to programming/development.

Answer (score 0):

No. The exchagne for developer questions only, is StackOverflow. That's the main reason we went for an general eosio StackExchange site. Using tags you can ask questions like "how is dpos dififerent than PoW" and tag it like `consensus algorithm`, or "how is it possible for eosio to be fee-less" and tag it `mining` or something similar.

A simple question like "Can I buy EOS in Bitfinex" could also be valid.

Those are not "programing" questions and 100% valid here.

Comment: This isn't stack overflow. It's a stackexchange, there are exchanges for Bitcoin, Chess, and even videogames.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride that's his point. This isn't SO, and this site shouldn't try to answer dev questions.  Those belong on SO.

Answer (score -2):

As a developer, I think the answer is that either this site is exclusively for  development questions, or it's exclusively for user questions.  If there are user questions here, then dev questions should only go to stackoverflow.  The culture for non-dev sites doesn't work well for devs; I want focused, answerable questions *only* a la SO, and I want unfocused questions removed.  That's probably a terrible way for user-friendly sites to operate, and a permissive message-board style site isn't useful for getting work done.

And I don't think I see the point of a developer-focused site.  Just use tags on SO itself.  So - downvote development questions and suggest that they ask on SO.  The worst possible outcome is a mixed site here, where we need to look both here and on SO for dev questions.  This site should be for non-dev questions exclusively.