# Can the site description be less dApp-centric?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The [tour page](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/tour) describes EOSIO SE as follows:

> EOS.IO Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users and developers of distributed applications built on top of the blockchain operating system, EOS.IO.

Above, it seems that "distributed applications" (dApps) are central to the purpose of the site, but many questions include protocol-level questions that may relate to the EOSIO code independent of a dApp.

For instance, questions about how to vote is not really dependent on dApps. Similarly, sending tokens between two users, implementing native private transactions, running a BP node, block validation algorithm, `nodeos` plugins, DPoS/BFT questions, and many others are not dApp-centric questions.

Granted, depending on one's definition of a dApp, someone may argue that a single contract such as `eosio.system` is a dApp, making most of EOSIO functionality an interaction among dApps. However, it may be the case that this would raise confusion as it does not appear to be a universally agreed upon definition, and even this extended interpretation would not cover questions such as e.g. DPoS algorithm or plugins.

Thus, I was wondering if it'd be possible for the EOSIO SE description to use a more general description. For instance, something along these lines:

> EOS.IO Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of EOSIO, a performance-based blockchain that provides an operating system for building large-scale distributed applications.

The definition being from [eos.io/introduction](https://eos.io/introduction):

> We propose EOSIO, a performance-based and self-governing blockchain that provides an operating system for building large-scale consumer-facing distributed applications.

Answer (score 3):

I would support that and think Stack Exchange is an easier way than putting such questions on Reddit, GirHub or inside the Telegram channel. Most of the time when I search for something, **I would also prefer curated and community approved answers around EOS in general from this plattform.**

If I remeber correctly there is a discussion about a similiar topic in [this thread](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-this-exchange-for-developer-questions-only).

I will add the tag 'feature-request' to this question, so the community support may change the describtion or joins the discussion.